# VBA ServerXMLHTTP https request with self signed certificate

Tags: vba, https, ssl-certificate

I'm using a ServerXMLHTTP object to make some http requests on an excel 2007 vba script.

But I need to connect to an https server which uses a self-signed SSL Certificate, so by default I get the message "The certificate authority is invalid or incorrect". Is there a way to configure the ServerXMLHTTP object so that it doesn't requires a CA Certificate?

Some sample code follows:

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
  objHTTP.Open "POST", "https://invernalia.homelinux.net", False, "user", "password"
  objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
  objHTTP.send ("")
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I used to have this problem for a while, and I only managed to get past it thanks to this:

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objHTTP.SetOption 2, objHTTP.GetOption(2)
objHTTP.Open "POST", "https://invernalia.homelinux.net", False, "user", "password"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
objHTTP.send ("")
```

I have found this here [setOption Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms763811(v=vs.85).aspx) and [getOption Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms753798(v=vs.85).aspx)

Here in this code I have just used `SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS` but you can try with others more specific:

- `SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_WRONG_USAGE`
- `SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID`
- `SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID`
- `SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA`

Comment: cool! that's it! you've earned it :) (stackoverflow tells me I must wait 11 hours to award the bounty, I'll be out of town these days, so please be patient if I can't connect to reward you, I'll do it once I'm back :)

Comment: Thanks! XMLHTTP with VBA is such badly documented that sometimes you just have to hope someone sometimes already had the same issue. Glad I could help! :)

Comment: SetOption was very helpful, just what I needed.  On my system I had to use "MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0" before SetOption took effect.

Comment: Substracting flags is kind of dangerous. And there is no need for parenthesis on `SetOption` and `Send` method calls. Use something like `objHTTP.SetOption 2, objHTTP.GetOption(2) And Not SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS` to turn off the specified flags.

Comment: The solution here is to trust the CA that was used to issue the self signed certificate rather than blindly disabling certificate validation.

Comment: If you dont have access to the constants, use this:
objHTTP.setOption(2) = 13056

Comment: What about in the case that you must select a certificate in order to post the url? Seems like .setOption 3, "CERTIFICATE?" is the option? But how exactly this works? the value after 3 should be the path of the certificate in local directory or the IE registry dir? Please help to expand a bit more. thanks

Answer (score 6):

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objHTTP.SetOption(2, objHTTP.GetOption(2) - SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS)
objHTTP.Open "POST", "https://invernalia.homelinux.net", False, "user", "password"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
objHTTP.send ("")
```

Got the above solution to work with a minor change. Instead of:

```
objHTTP.SetOption(2, objHTTP.GetOption(2) - SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS)
```

I used:

```
objHTTP.SetOption(2) = (objHTTP.GetOption(2) - SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS)
```

Otherwise I get an error of:

> Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0414' Cannot use parentheses
>   when calling a Sub objHTTP.SetOption(2, objHTTP.GetOption(2) -
>   SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS)

referenced from:
[SXH_OPTION_IGNORE_SERVER_SSL_CERT_ERROR_FLAGS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: For the error '800a0414', see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14908329/1534346) by @Helen

Comment: Just remove the parentheses on `SetOption` like this `objHTTP.SetOption 2, objHTTP.GetOption(2) And Not SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS`

Comment: Just use "call objHTTP.SetOptions(... params)"