# Including Parenthisis inside a VBA db.Execute String

Tags: sql, vba, string-formatting

How do I format this line of code correctly to allow me to have the parenthesis inside the statement string?

> db.Execute("SQL DB", "INSERT INTO ABPCahirMIS.dbo.TESTDB (TEST)  VALUES(1) ")

Comment: what do you mean exactly? could you give an example statement of what the statement would be like?

Comment: @Jeremy C. When I run it it tells me I cannot use a parenthesis when calling a sub?

Comment: try putting call before your statement like so: Call db.Execute("SQL DB", "INSERT INTO ABPCahirMIS.dbo.TESTDB (TEST) VALUES(1) ")

Comment: you might want to read this if that one doesn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902134/cannot-use-parentheses-when-calling-a-sub-error-800a0414-vbs

Comment: If the result of the call is not being assigned to a variable, VBA doesn't want the outer parenthesis around the Execute call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VBA, if you call a sub, you don't add parentheses to the call, eg:

```
db.Execute "SQL DB", "INSERT INTO ABPCahirMIS.dbo.TESTDB (TEST) VALUES(1)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Dim dbs As DAO.Database, sql as String
Set dbs = "SQL DB"
sql = INSERT INTO ABPCahirMIS.dbo.TESTDB (TEST) VALUES(1)
dbs.Execute sql, dbFailOnError
```