# How can i call Single Classic ASP Parameterized Function With and Without Assigning to Variable? Without CALL

Tags: function, variables, vbscript, asp-classic

I Defined a function with parameters in Classic Asp Which returns the value.

### Calling Two times a Classic ASP function without using CALL

> 1.Store the Returned value
>
> 2.Not Storing the Returned value( not like CALL funcitonname)

```
 Function concatenate(first, last, operation)
    Dim full
    full = first & last
    IF operation="I" THEN
      'Storing the value in database and returning Result Set
       concatenate = conn.Execute(full)
    END IF
    IF operation="U" THEN
      'Updating the value in database without returning Result Set
       conn.Execute(full)
    END IF
  End Function

  ' Here is the usage of returning value from function. 
  dim rs
  SET rs= concatenate("First", "Last", "I") 'Executing Correctly
  CALL concatenate("First", "Last", "I")    'Executing But not my requirement Because need to change many times Cause by Just adding a Parameter
  concatenate("First", "Last", "U")          'Compilation Error
```

How can we call the Same Function Without Storing Value.?
Please Help me regarding this **Classic ASP Functions**

Comment: what is the compilation error?

Comment: you try with my answer below

Comment: This is the Error, cannot use parentheses when calling a sub error in vbscript.. Thanks i will Try your answer

Comment: updated my answer, it's better that you include the error message in your question.

Comment: @Prashee the answer is in the error, don't call it with parentheses *(i.e `concatenate "First", "Last", "U")*.

Comment: @Lankymart that's a bad idea, why use a function when you call it like a `sub`

Comment: @Niladri it makes no difference, a `Function` will behave like a `Sub` if you don't assign it to a value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub Error 800A0414 VBS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902134/cannot-use-parentheses-when-calling-a-sub-error-800a0414-vbs)

Comment: @Lankymart.. Thanks for Reference. I am not getting error with Single Parameter. When i Changed the Parameters I got this Error. CALL FunctionName is Better Approach. But I should change 10 thousand times. So that I should not add CALL.. 
Can u please give me a best suggestion.

Comment: @Prashee this is because what you think is calling a function with parentheses is actually just your first argument, [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/09/15/what-do-you-mean-cannot-use-parentheses/) explains it in detail but one of the creators behind VBScript. Adjusted [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46686404/692942) to include a link.

Comment: @Lankymart Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A lot of misinformation here, you don't have to change anything inside your function, a function can return a value or not based on how you call it.

```vb
'Don't return a value
 concatenate "First", "Last", "U"

 'If you still want to call with parentheses
 Call concatenate("First", "Last", "U")
```

---

If you are wondering why this works;

```vb
'What no "cannot use parentheses" error??
concatenate("First")
```

then here is some light reading for you.

- [What do you mean "cannot use parentheses?" - By @EricLippert](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/09/15/what-do-you-mean-cannot-use-parentheses/)

Comment: @Niladri I was writing this before your slapdash edit.

Comment: ok I see you are to the point after copying an already posted answer. great.

Comment: @Niladri personally I wouldn't usually answer these types of questions as they've been done to death already, but as I didn't agree with the changes to the `Function` wanted to clarify the actual reason their code was failing. That's not to say that your amendment wasn't correct, there was no need to remove your answer.

Comment: @Folks Both are saying facts. I posted this question to know the possibilities when we call like Same Line when they are Returning or Not Returning for FUNCTION. By changing something in Function Headding.

Comment: @Prashee I'm lost, what part hasn't been answered by the provided links?

Comment: @Lankymart You gave me the links that shows i can not do in the way that what i desired to do. You have answered nicely. Thanks.. you want me to accept your answer? I will.