# VBA Calling function with / without Parenthesis

Tags: excel, vba

i was playing with some VBA when i noticed this (for me) strange behaviour. I know that by default, Excel VBA passes arguments by reference, so i would expect from both 'ways of calling' the sub `TestSub` the same result. Why is that when i call it with parenthesis it behaves like the argument was passed `ByVal`?

My expectations:

```
TestSub (intSomeNumber) 'prints 15
TestSub intSomeNumber   'prints 15
```

Reality:

```
TestSub (intSomeNumber) 'prints 10
TestSub intSomeNumber   'prints 15
```

Here is the code:

```
Sub Macro_1()
    Dim intSomeNumber As Integer: intSomeNumber = 10

    ' If i'll call TestSub without parenthesis
    ' the value of intSomeNumber will be changed to 15 as expected
    TestSub intSomeNumber

    ' If i'll call TestSub with parenthesis
    ' the value won't change, so the result printed via Debug.Print will be 10
    'TestSub (intSomeNumber)

    Debug.Print CStr(intSomeNumber)
End Sub

Private Sub TestSub(argIntSomeNumber As Integer)
    argIntSomeNumber = 15
End Sub
```

Comment: You only need to use brackets when the function is on the right hand side of an assignment expression.  Your use of brackets  is causing your parameter to be evaluated as an expression which yields a value hence the difference in behaviours you are seeing.  This is the normal correct behaviour of VBA.

Comment: Chip Pearson has a good [explanation](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/byrefbyval.aspx) of `ByRef` vs `ByVal`: "Even if a called procedure has declared its parameters as `ByRef`, you can force those to be `ByVal` by enclosing each argument within parentheses."

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/09/15/what-do-you-mean-cannot-use-parentheses/

Comment: @Sam Don't think that that's the point of my 'problem'. Freeflows and noodles comments explained it i guess (i would accept either of those as an answer) i do understand now why and when to use parenthesis in VBA when calling subs/functions. If it's duplicate of somthing i'd say it's closer to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902134/cannot-use-parentheses-when-calling-a-sub-error-800a0414-vbs