# How to set correct syntax if (fso.FileExists("")) after checking with fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")

Tags: vbscript, file-exists, fso

I'm struggling with correct syntax for setting the path in:

```
if (fso.FileExists("myfile.txt")) then ....
```

I use this:

```
set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Mypath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
if (fso.FileExists("myfile.txt")) then...
```

as i understand fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".") knows the path from where my script was launched
and when tested i can see the correct path with:

```
call MsgBox(Mypath)
```

for example the MsgBox is showing c:\users\user\desktop
that's where the script was launched and where i create my files.
I cannot use directly a path because it needs to be dynamic, files will be created and replaced
if exists at the same path the script was launched.

I hope it was clear enough, and that someone can answer this!
I'v read a lot of examples but none are covering this particular need.
thanks

Comment: You can use the [BuildPath Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/z0z2z1zt(v=vs.84)). `if (fso.FileExists(fso.buildpath(Mypath,"myfile.txt"))) then`

Comment: Hello @Flakes, i've tried your code it should work but i get an error message. Error: Call of sub function doesn't allow parenthesis error code: 0x800A0414

Comment: @Flakes this what i did:                                                                                      `set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Mypath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
if (fso.FileExists(fso.buildpath(Mypath,"test.txt"))) then
fso.DeleteFile(Mypath,"t_")end if`

Comment: What are you trying to do with `fso.DeleteFile(Mypath,"t_")`? If you are going to use the full path to the file in multiple places, store it in a  variable and reuse it. `fullPath = fso.buildpath(Mypath,"test.txt")`.

Comment: @Flakes what this is suppose to do is to delete and replace it later in the code. If i launch the VBscript twice in the same path, its to make sure the file is deleted before the rest of the code recreates the same file, because the file name will never change.

Comment: `fso.DeleteFile fullPath` ? (The error you were getting is [because of this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14908329/1682881) )

Comment: @Flakes you mean like this ?`set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Mypath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
    Fullpath = fso.buildpath(Mypath,"test.txt")
    if (fso.FileExists(Fullpath,"test.txt")) then
        fso.DeleteFile(Fullpath,"test.txt")
    end if`

Comment: `if (fso.FileExists(Fullpath)) then fso.DeleteFile(Fullpath)`

Comment: @Flakes I cannot vote on your answer because you did not create one.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim FSO 'As FileSystemObject
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If (FSO.FileExists("C:\Foobar.txt") Then
    {statements}
End If

Set FSO = Nothing
```