# What is the proper syntax when calling VBScript via Automation Anywhere Run Script command?

Tags: vbscript, automationanywhere

I have this VBScript for scrolling vertically / down a webpage, but when I execute the script, I get the following error:
Error in Script -
1044 Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub

Here is the script syntax:

```
Function scrollWin() 
  window.scrollBy(0, 100)
End Function
```

Note. I'm using the Automation Anywhere "Run Script" command to execute the vb-script.
Could I get some guidance as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub Error 800A0414 VBS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902134/cannot-use-parentheses-when-calling-a-sub-error-800a0414-vbs)

Comment: For reference (seen as though you have already accepted a duplicate answer), if you looked at the duplicate target you would know you could also just prefix with `Call` to still use parentheses, like this; `Call window.scrollBy(0, 100)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
window.scrollBy(0, 100)
```

To:

```
window.scrollBy 0, 100
```

Comment: [This isn’t a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14908329/692942) (answered over 8 years ago), flag and move on. All answering does is dilute existing canonical questions and answers. Plus your answer doesn’t mention the use of `Call` to allow you to still call a `Sub` with parentheses.