# How to call a sub that has a parameter?

Tags: excel, vba

The following code produces different results based on how the `ChangeString` sub is called.

- If I use `ChangeString (str)`, the message box returns "First String".
- If I use `ChangeString str` or `Call ChangeString(str)` it returns "Second String".

They all should me equivalent ways to call a sub and pass it an argument, so I expected to get "Second String" every time.

I tried the code on both Excel 2016 and 2021.

```vb
Sub TryByRef()

    Dim str As String

    str = "First String"

    ChangeString (str)
    'ChangeString str
    'Call ChangeString(str)

    MsgBox str

End Sub


Sub ChangeString(ByRef s As String)
    s = "Second String"
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't use parenthesis when calling a Sub. `ChangeString str` - If you do, expect problems in some cases.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14908329/8422953

Comment: The clue it gives you is that it puts a space before the `(`

Comment: `MsgBox` obeys the same rules: when you don't have or don't care for a procedure's return value, you do `MsgBox str`, without the parentheses. When you need the return value, you do `result = MsgBox(str)`, with the parentheses. `ChangeString` doesn't have a return value, so you do `ChangeString "First String"`

Comment: Stuck to the procedure name as in `MsgBox(`, the parens mean "argument list". With a space between, they mean "expression". When you put an _expression_ inside parentheses as an argument, what you're passing `ByRef` is a reference to the _result_ of that expression.... which you don't have a reference to, so `ChangeString` is mutating the result of the `(str)` expression, and `MsgBox str` says `"First String"` because the `str` variable itself was never passed to `ChangeString`.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2003/09/15/what-do-you-mean-cannot-use-parentheses/

Answer (score 1):

The parentheses are converting the original string into a new string.  Removing the converting will return the correct result.

```
Sub TryByRef()

    Dim str As String

    str = "First String"
    Rem Subroutines shou
    ChangeString (str)

    Debug.Print "Call with parentheses str"

    ChangeString str

    Debug.Print "Call without parentheses str"

End Sub


Sub ChangeString(ByRef s As String)

    s = "Second String"

End Sub
```

[image: Result]