# The certificate authority is invalid or incorrect

Tags: rest, asp-classic

Have called many restful services from asp before - but this one has me stumped.
First my func looks like

```
Set objHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP") 
with objHTTP 
.open "post", x_posturl, False 
.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
.send x_xmlstr
end with
```

and the error returned is

> msxml3.dll error '80072f0d'  The certificate authority is invalid or
>   incorrect

so, googled a bit and suggestion was to add line

```
.setOption 2, 13056
```

this gives error

> msxml3.dll error '80072f0c'  A certificate is required to complete
>   client authentication

I then contacted service supplier and they suggested

> Click on the certificate error next to the address bar, view the
>   certificate, select Details, select Copy to File, and download it to a
>   file.  Install that into your trusted certificates on your server to
>   stop the error appearing when trying to submit data.

So, tried that using instructions [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2007/04/10/installing-a-self-signed-certificate-as-a-trusted-root-ca-in-windows-vista.aspx) - but still no joy, any help appreciated

Comment: think have installed cert correctly - but now get error

msxml3.dll error '80072f99' 
No credentials were available in the client certificate. 

this person has similar issue  http://forums.aspfree.com/asp-development-5/msxml3-dll-error-80072f99-security-error-occurred-359962.html howver the link to solution is no-longer active ;((

Comment: am now trying to give NETWORK SERVICE read access to 

c:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys

however i get error 

"failure to enumerate objects in container - access is denied"

any ideas welcome

Comment: have taken ownership of folder and added permission for IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool and now get error msxml4.dll error '80072f8f' A security error occurred 
is this still folder permission error?

Comment: also changed serverxml to MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.4.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA ServerXMLHTTP https request with self signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11573022) (Same issue with the same library just in VBA so the difference is minimal).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A certificate is required to complete client authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20242029)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the server located at `x_posturl` has a certificate that is misconfigured, or that your client computer doesn't contain/recognize the certificate's root authority (most likely). There are a few options to fix:

1. Have them fix their certificate if it's misconfigured.
2. If their certificate is valid, but with a root authority your machine doesn't recognize, then you need to install the root authority certificate locally.
3. Instruct `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` to ignore certificate errors, which appears to be answered here: [VBA ServerXMLHTTP https request with self signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573022/vba-serverxmlhttp-https-request-with-self-signed-certificate)
4. Change `x_posturl` to start with `http://` instead of `https://`— if it's supported by the provider. Would not recommend this in a production scenario though.

Can you share specifically what `x_posturl` is? We should be able to debug by looking at the SSL handshake.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find the solution by passing in a param.

**objHTTP.SetOption 2, objHTTP.GetOption(2)**

```
Dim objHTTP
Set objHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objHTTP.SetOption 2, objHTTP.GetOption(2)
objHTTP.Open "post", x_posturl, False 
objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHTTP.Send x_xmlstr
```