# A certificate is required to complete client authentication

Tags: vbscript

I have written the following code and when I run the scheduler, get this error : "A certificate is required to complete client authentication, msxml3.dll error '80072f0c'".

```
Dim objXML
Set objXML = CreateObject ("MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp") 
objXML.open "GET", "https://test.moneymapwebpro.com/synchClients.aspx", false
objXML.send
Set objXML = Nothing
```

Please let me know , why the error message occurs.

Comment: How is asp.net related to the question?

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft [KB302080](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302080):

> Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) certificate support was added to the
>   ServerXMLHTTP request object with the release of MSXML version 3.0
>   Service Pack 1. To make any SSL requests from the Web server,
>   ServerXMLHTTP expects a client digital certificate to be installed,
>   even if the target Web server does not require a client certificate.

You  need to use to a new version of MSXML -- at least MSXML 3.0 SP2 -- and install a client certificate.

Comment: I have created and assigned a self signed certificate but I am still getting error.

Comment: I have created a new certificate which is not a self signed but still getting error.