# MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP - The parameter is incorrect

Tags: xml, vbscript

I'm trying to use the following code to download a webpage:

```
dim xmlhttp : set xmlhttp = createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
dim fso : set fso = createobject ("scripting.filesystemobject")
dim newfile : set newfile = fso.createtextfile("getVersion.htm", true)

xmlhttp.SetOption SXH_OPTION_IGNORE_SERVER_SSL_CERT_ERROR_FLAGS, true
xmlhttp.open "GET", "https://mysite:8443/remote/epo.GetVersion", "username", "password"
xmlhttp.send

newfile.write (xmlhttp.responseText)
newfile.close
```

However, it fails with "mxm13.dll: The parameter is incorrect." on line 6.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The 3<sup>rd</sup> argument to [`open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763809(v=vs.85).aspx) should be a boolean, specifying whether or not the request should be asynchronous.

```
oServerXMLHTTPRequest.open bstrMethod, bstrUrl, bAsync, bstrUser, bstrPassword
```

> **bstrMethod**
>
> The HTTP method used to open the connection, such as PUT or
>   PROPFIND. For ServerXMLHTTP, this parameter is case-sensitive and the
>   method name must be entered in all upper-case letters.
>
> **bstrUrl**
>
> The
>   requested URL. This can be either an absolute URL, such as
>   "http://example.com/Mypath/Myfile.asp", or a relative URL, such as
>   "../MyPath/MyFile.asp".
>
> **bAsync** (optional)
>
> Boolean. Indicator as to
>   whether the call is asynchronous. The default is False (the call does
>   not return immediately).
>
> **bstrUser** (optional)
>
> The name of the user for
>   authentication.
>
> **bstrPassword** (optional)
>
> The password for
>   authentication. This parameter is ignored if the user parameter is
>   Null or missing.

---

With a bit of experimentation and help from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573022/vba-serverxmlhttp-https-request-with-self-signed-certificate), I think you just need to change

```
xmlhttp.SetOption SXH_OPTION_IGNORE_SERVER_SSL_CERT_ERROR_FLAGS, true
```

to

```
xmlhttp.SetOption 2, xmlhttp.GetOption(2) - SXH_OPTION_IGNORE_SERVER_SSL_CERT_ERROR_FLAGS
```

Comment: I've tried adding true and false, but the error is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows 8, Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012/2012R2, you might have to apply the following HotFix, which fixed this problem for me in a similar scenario:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2968741/error-0x80070057-when-sql-server-communicates-to-a-web-server-using-st

For further info you can also [read this post](http://www.ryadel.com/en/msxml2-xmlhttp-serverxmlhttp-error-0x80070057-parameter-incorrect-post-http-request-t-sql-server-2008-2012-sp-fix/) on my blog or take a look to [this other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26765782/msxml3-dll-in-context-sp-oamethod-send).