# Function that copies a file from Sharepoint URL to a local path in Microsoft Access VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Hi I have a button in an Access form that loads files from my computers shared network drive but doesnt load files from our sharepoint.

So I'm trying to just create a function that, with a URL and a path, copies the file at the end of the URL and copies it to the path

I don't know if it matters, but my computer has limited internet access so it can only access our sharepoint site and no other websites

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code? What is the exact problem you encounter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download a file from Sharepoint with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42419486/how-to-download-a-file-from-sharepoint-with-vba)